# Google Maps API v3 Different Color Markers w/ Coffeescript

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript, google-maps-markers

I am trying to set up different color markers for based on types from google maps api
but for some reason its only showing the orange color from the array inside the request object
but yet the console.log shows all the different types.

What am I doing wrong? How can i get the markers to be different colors as opposed to being all orange.

I wrote it in coffeescript below:

```
jQuery ($) ->


map = null
infowindow = null
request = null
icons = null
specific_icon = null
marker = null
markers = null
value = null
collection = null

init = () ->
    # Setup map options
    mapOptions =
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.54809, -122.1230)
        zoom: 11
        streetViewControl: false
        panControl: false
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        zoomControlOptions: 
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        mapTypeControlOptions:
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']

    # Create the map with above options in div
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOptions)

    # Drop marker in the same location
    marker = new google.maps.Marker
        map: map
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        position: mapOptions.center
        icon: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png'

    # Create a request field to hold POIs
    request = 
        location: new google.maps.LatLng(47.54809, -122.1230)
        radius: 4000
        types: ['store','food','park','school']

    # Create the infowindow(popup over marker)
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

    # Setup places nearby search (it setups points near the center marker)
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback)


# Create the callback function to loop thru the places (object)
callback = (results, status) ->
        if status is google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK
            for index, attrs of results
                 createMarker results[index]


# Create the actual markers for the looped places
createMarker = (place) ->

    collection = request.types

    icons =
        store: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png'
        food: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png'
        park: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png'
        school:'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/orange-dot.png'

    for index, value of collection 
        marker = new google.maps.Marker
            map: map
            position: place.geometry.location
            icon: icons[value]
        console.log value

        # Create a click listener that shows a info window with places name
        google.maps.event.addListener marker, 'click', ->
            infowindow.setContent(place.name)
            infowindow.open(map,@)



init()
```

Any and all help is appreciated 
-David

Comment: If you change the order of the icons or remove the orange-dot.png, do they still come up orange?

Comment: I'm not familiar with coffeescript, but it seems you create 4 markers for each place at the same position. The last marker(and therefore the most top and only one you see) of the 4 markers will always be the orange marker(make the markers draggable, maybe you'll find the other markers behind). You must fetch the type out of `place.types` and create a single marker for each place instead of iterating over `request.types` .

Comment: @Nix i am getting all of my different markers with the same color, that being orange

Comment: @Dr.Molle is right you are placing 4 on top of each other.

Comment: @David Chase: of course place.types gives more than 1 type. you must iterate over place.types and when you find a type where a icon is defined for create the marker and go to the next place(when none of the types matches an icon, create a marker with a fallback-icon)

Comment: I did that before, with a switch case, but i was trying to use an object to hold all of the icon pngs this one can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/E4myT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the issue is solved by the comments, an suggestion how to hold the icons in a single object:

create a function(where you have the object populated with the URL's).

When you call the function without an argument, return an array with the keys(you may use it as types-option for the request).

When the function has been called with an argument(place.types) find the desired icon inside the object and return the url(which you may use as icon-option of the marker)

**Example-function:**
*(please forgive me when it's no good coding-style, it's my first coffeescript)*

```
gettypes = (types=[]) ->
    icons =
        store: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png'
        food: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png'
        park: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png'
        school:'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/orange-dot.png'

    if !types.length
      for key of icons
        key
    else
      for icon in types
        if icon of icons
          return icons[icon]
        'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/info_circle.png'
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/3TN7f/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/3TN7f/)

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate you doing this and in coffeescript!